# BroadcastReceiver stops working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In general i have a service that sends an intent to my activity which is ALWAYS on every 6 sec and a `BroadcastReceiver` everytime on receive updates a timer.

I found by accident that after a while ( this is random ) that the particular receiver stops working.

`OnPause` i `unregister` it and `onResume` i register it again.

Also this happens randomly in any devices and android versions.

I found by researching on the web , that after `onReceive` the receiver is ready to killed by Android but mine keeps getting intents.

"Receiver Lifecycle

A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.
"

FYI i have declare it like this inside my activity

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

        Log.i("Intent received", "+_ " + intent.getAction());
        if (intent.getAction().equals(TEST)) {
        //do sth
        } else {

        //do sth else
        }


    }
}
```

Thans a lot even for taking the time to read :).

I dont declare anythin to my manifest and as for my logcat i must be over my phone the moment it happens. The service is a simple send broadcast after one async task. The last test i made was ensuring that the code from the service was running by logging the beeing sent. And the service kept on.

I am away from my code write now but i think there will be no help because is very simple. Thnaks

Comment: Can you post, activity, service , manifest and logcat please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i could still figure out but I find a solution to my problem

Timer now is in the activity and receiver is sending the event but after 10000 tries i want to trigger the END EVENT. Now the receiver since he didn't work i couldn't get it but now i Start an intent with extras for the same activity always with flags new_task and clear_top.

No matter if my receiver is working or not, since the service is ok i will start the specific Activity and pseudo-show the END EVENT.

PS:: This behavior isn't always trigger but sometimes. So now i am ok.

If i am not understood please comment and ask anything. Thanks